# Filtering output

Tags: 7, entities

I am creating templates using hook_theme. It works fine, but should I be filtering the output? I am accessing it via ['und'][0]['value'], but this doesn't seem right

Specifically in the code below `$model_name, $description`

```
function dc_car_guide_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){   
    return array(
        'dc_car_makes' => array(
            'variables' => array('makes' => array()),
            'template' => 'theme/makes'
        ),
        'dc_car_models' => array(
            'variables' => array('models' => array(), 'make' => ''),
            'template' => 'theme/models'
        ),      
        'dc_car_model' => array(
            'variables' => array('photos' => array(), 'make' => '', 'model' => '', 'description' => ''),
            'template' => 'theme/model'
        ),      
    );
}


function dc_car_guide_model($model_id)
{
    $model = entity_load_single('field_collection_item', $model_id);
    $host_entity = $model->hostEntity();
    $make_node = node_load($host_entity->nid);
    $model_name = $model->field_model_name['und'][0]['value'];
    $description = $model->field_writeup['und'][0]['value'];

    return theme('dc_car_model', array('photos' => array(), 'make' => $make_node->title, 'model' =>$model_name, 'description' => $description));
}
```

Comment: You are correct to assume raw field values retrieved with ['und'][0]['value'] are unsanitized and thus not secure for direct output. Nikit's answer shows a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

PLease, read [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).
So you'll get next:

```
<?php
function dc_car_guide_model($model_id) {
  $model = entity_load_single('field_collection_item', $model_id);
  $host_entity = $model->hostEntity();
  $make_node = node_load($host_entity->nid);

  $field = field_get_items('node', $make_node, 'field_model_name');
  $model_name = render(field_view_value('node', $make_node, 'field_model_name', $field[0])); // Remove render, if you want work with arrays on theme function.

  $field = field_get_items('ENTITY', $model, 'field_writeup');
  $description = render(field_view_value('ENTITY', $model, 'field_writeup', $field[0])); // Not sure is this correct, since I don't have info about your entity.

  return theme('dc_car_model', array('photos' => array(), 'make' => $make_node->title, 'model' =>$model_name, 'description' => $description));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. field_model_name and field_writeup are both part of a field collection. What is the process for a field collection?

Comment: "field_model_name" was fixed on code. for ENTITY you should replace by your entity type: field collection entity, I cann't say how it called. Try first just using "entity"

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer, using Entity API module, you could do something like:

```
function dc_car_guide_model($make_node) {
  // Load parent node, allow passed node object or nid
  $make_node = is_object($make_node) ? $make_node : node_load($make_node);
  // Get entity wrapper for easy access to properties and field values 
  $make_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $make_node);
  // Fetch field values
  $model_name = $make_wrapper->field_collection_item->field_model_name->value();
  $description = $make_wrapper->field_collection_item->field_writeup->value();
  // Output
  return theme('dc_car_model', array('photos' => array(), 'make' => $make_node->title, 'model' =>$model_name, 'description' => $description));
}
```

As an extra, although the above method is fine for outputting sanitized markup, Drupal provides the following functions for manual sanitizing of variables

- [Sanitization functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/group/sanitization/7)

See also http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code for information on writing secure code.